# Many-to-Many Relationships in EF4 with "Shared" columns

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Disclaimer: Strictly speaking, what I have here is not a many-to-many relationship, but given that it's using an associative table, I figured it would be better to be slightly less accurate in order to give a better idea of what I'm doing.

I have the equivalent of the following three tables in my database:

```
Customer
---------
CustomerID PK
...

CustomerAddress
---------
CustomerID PK, FK -> Customer
AddressNo  PK
... address columns ...

CustomerPrimaryAddress
--------------
CustomerID PK, FK -> Customer
AddressNo      FK -> CustomerAddress (with CustomerID, so CustomerID 
                                      participates in both relationships)
```

If it's not obvious, the intent here is to allow for multiple addresses per customer, while designating at most one address per customer as "primary". I'm using an associative table to avoid placing a nullable `PrimaryAddressNumber` column on `Customer`, then creating a foreign key from `Customer` to `CustomerAddress`.

This is all well and good, but EF then places the `CustomerPrimaryAddress` entity in my model. Since its one and only purpose is to serve as an associative table, I have no need to represent this table in code. I removed the `CustomerPrimaryAddress` table from the conceptual model, then created an association between `Customer` and `CustomerAddress` like so:

```
Table          Customer   CustomerAddress
Multiplicity   1          0..1
```

I then mapped the association to use the `CustomerPrimaryAddress` table from the storage model, and all of the columns mapped just fine, or so I thought.

My issue is that now EF is complaining that `CustomerID` in `CustomerPrimaryAddress` is being mapped to two locations in my association, as it's mapped to both `Customer` and `CustomerAddress`.

Is there any way around this? I would prefer not to add a nullable column to `Customer` to represent the primary address number, as not only is this not a pleasant option from a DBA perspective, EF will also complain about having a cyclical relationship and I'll have to break inserts up in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking out loud here:

```
Customer
---------
CustomerID PK
...

CustomerAddress
---------
AddressNo  PK
CustomerID FK -> Customer, non-nullable
... address columns ...

CustomerPrimaryAddress
--------------
CustomerID PK, FK -> Customer
AddressNo      FK -> CustomerAddress
```

This *seems* like it should get the cardinalities right, but I may have missed something.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at; in my design, `AddressNo` was not going to be a unique column within `CustomerAddress` (it would be unique within a given `CustomerId`, thus forming the compound primary key). I suppose I could just give `CustomerAddress` a single-column identity key and make a (functionally useless, but required for the FK) unique index on `CustomerAddress` for the two columns.

Comment: Of all of the compromises, this seems like the most desirable. While I'd prefer to keep `CustomerID` as part of the primary key for `CustomerAddress` (and it just rubs me the wrong way to design my db to fit my ORM), this should work. If nothing else miraculous comes around, I'll accept this. Thanks!